# How to setup multiple way of authentication in Jenkins such as LDAP and Jenkins User database?

Tags: authentication, jenkins

Actually the authentication into our Jenkins is done through LDAP.

Some people in my team are not member of the LDAP.

Is there a way to use both LDAP and Jenkins user database?

Comment: It might be possible with the mixing-security-realm-plugin: https://github.com/jenkinsci/mixing-security-realm-plugin

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible as described. The feature request is [JENKINS-15063](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-15063).

However, it is possible to approximate in a few ways (though the Jenkins user database still won't be usable).

- For multiple [LDAP](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ldap) realms you can set up a single proxy server that combines the forests.
- Using [PAM](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pam-auth) you can define multiple authentication sources and fallbacks in e.g. `/etc/pam.d/jenkins`

Answer (score -5):

Yes that's possible and requires 2 steps:

1. **Add a user**
   Navigate to Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Configure Global Security.
   Under Authorization you need to configure who can do what. You can add LDAP groups and/or users and fine tune what they are allowed to do.
   If you enabled Matrix-based or Project/Matrix-based authorization then you have a field to add new users/groups. You can add users that are known to LDAP or not known.
2. **Add Credentials**
   If you added a user that is not known to LDAP you need to create the credentials in Jenkins (i.e. password). 
   Navigate to Jenkins -> Credentials -> System -> Global Credentials -> Add Credentials 
   Then add username and password.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. At least with Jenkins 2.150.3. It gives me ```401 Invalid password/token for user: non_ldap_user```

Comment: credential are used to access third party sites/tools, not for login in to jenkins