# create a local user in jenkins along side LDAP authentication

Tags: jenkins

The purpose is to create a local user in jenkins(granting admin rights) along side the LDAP group authentication so that this "local" user can perform all admin actions whenever the LDAP authentication is not working.
I can set up active directory user(valid users with a valid id), but i want to explore the possibility of setting  up "local" jenkins user
I tried to figure this out through JENKINS JIRA but there is no mention of jenkins local user.

Can anyone help me figure this out.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49938149/how-to-setup-multiple-way-of-authentication-in-jenkins-such-as-ldap-and-jenkins

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't.

When you activate LDAP authentication, you automatically disable Jenkins' internal user database. Both cannot co-exist.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the accepted answer in that Jenkins does not currently appear to support the simultaneous use of internal authentication and LDAP authentication.

That said, what I do to work around this is:

1. Run a local copy (i.e. on the Jenkins system itself) of slapd
2. Configure Jenkins with LDAP authentication, and point him to *both* my local LDAP directory and our organization's directory

See screenshots:
[image: Configure multiple LDAP directories]

[image: Set up local directory]

By doing so, I'm able to create (within the local LDAP instance) a handful of service accounts, and also utilize my org's LDAP authentication for everything else. (On a side note, I use the "Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy" to manage authz.)

Setting up a local directory is more effort at the outset, but it solves the problem you are describing -- at least until a better solution is available.

Answer (score 2):

There is an improvement filed here to support local users and LDAP users at the same time: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-3404

Answer (score 2):

[Active Directory Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/active-directory/) has an **option for a fallback user** since V2.5