# Is it possible to use both SAML and Jenkins internal db to manage users?

Tags: security, jenkins, saml

I would like to be able to sign in with both users from Jenkins' own user database and Azure (via SAML Plugin) credentials.

[Manage Jenkins - *Configure Global Security* screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9KF4.png)

With SAML 2.0 setup, I am able to login with Azure credentials and I am able to
view the /login page for standard login. However, my username and
passwords don't appear to work even just after signing up.

I noticed in the Manage Jenkins UI that the SAML 2.0 selection is a radio button instead of a checkbox. Does this suggest that using both methods isn't possible?

I am able to manipulate the Jenkins config.xml directly, or any other files on the machine, if there is a way of getting this to work via configuration.

I notice these security realm settings changing, when I jump between SAML and jenkins managed users via the UI, in the config.xml of Jenkins. Are multiple supported?

```
<   <securityRealm class="hudson.security.HudsonPrivateSecurityRealm">
---
>   <securityRealm class="org.jenkinsci.plugins.saml.SamlSecurityRealm" plugin="saml@1.1.2">
```

Comment: This is more a Jenkins than Azure question. This open issue seems to suggest Jenkins will not support multiple auth providers enabled at the same time: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-29162

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49938149/how-to-setup-multiple-way-of-authentication-in-jenkins-such-as-ldap-and-jenkins